# how to bind varible in sql/plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, talend

My query is

```
with dates_table as (
                 SELECT to_date(:begin_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') + ROWNUM - 1 cal_day
                        FROM dual
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= to_date(:end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') - to_date(:begin_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') + 1)
    SELECT '1' AS ID,
           'bank' AS DESC,
           cal_day AS dates,
           (SUM (
               CASE
                  WHEN S_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS (cal_day, 0) - 13
                                  AND ADD_MONTHS (cal_day, 0) - 7
                  THEN
                     VOLUME
                  ELSE
                     0
               END))
              LAST_14_days,
           (SUM (
               CASE
                  WHEN S_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS (cal_day, 0) - 6
                                  AND ADD_MONTHS (cal_day, 0)
                  THEN
                     VOLUME
                  ELSE
                     0
               END))
              last 7day
      FROM abc, day
      where day.cal_day between '13-NOV-16' and '22-MAR-17'
      group by cal_day
      order by cal_day
```

Comment: OK, that is your query... so what is your question?

Comment: could  u tell me how bind variable in that query ..i am new in sql/plsql

Comment: There is no variable defined in there.  Are you talking about a PL/SQL block where you define your own variable and want to use it?  Are you talking about a PL/SQL Block in a function or procedure and you're trying to make use of a parameter?  Are you trying to run a SQL Statement from another language and want to know how to use parameterised queries?  The context matters....

Comment: So I am guessing you want to pass `cal_day` as a parameter somehow. What is going to call this? Is it part of an interactive report, a Java application, a batch ETL process?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Talend ETL Process

Comment: OK. I've never used Talend so no idea how you define parameters in that.

Comment: Are you talking about bind values for `:begin_date` and `:end_date`; or replacing the fixed dates in the final `where` clause; or should they be the same? (Why is that filter needed if the CTE is generating the range you want anyway?) There are other issues with your query - it looks like `day` be `dates_table`, you have invalid column aliases, you're relying on implicit conversion...

Comment: binding values bind values for :begin_date and :end_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may replace you parametric sql in the upper part with the following :

```
SELECT to_date('&&begin_date', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + ROWNUM - 1 cal_day
                        FROM dual
                  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= to_date('&&end_date', 'dd/mm/yyyy') - to_date('&&begin_date', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + 1)
....
```

For numeric values you may directly define variables without single quotes`''`, but you should include quotes for date or string type parameters. In each case use `double ampersand` so that repeating parameters( you have more than one `:begin_date` ) don't prompt you(normally, you can use `single ampersand` also, but in this case you'll be prompted for each parameter even if they're the same )

Comment: Talend understands and lets you supply substitution variables, but not bind variables?

Comment: yes it accept bind variable ! like above solution. Thanks for ur help